# 'Hamburger' icon and navlinks do not appear when I reduce the screen size

Tags: css, hamburger-menu

I have a navigation bar created using html, css, and js. I added some media queries to handle the screen size reduction, and I want a 'hamburger' menu to appear when the screen scales down to a smaller size. However, the `nav` links are completely disappearing when I resize, and the hamburger menu doesn't appear at all.

```js
function toggleMenu() {
  console.log('Function called...');
  const navLinks = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
  navLinks.classList.toggle('open');
}
```

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.nav-links ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  /* display: inline; */
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.nav-links li {
  margin-right: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 1.2px;
}

.nav-links a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: black;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 200;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  color: black;
}

.nav-toggle {
  /* display: none; */
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color white;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav-links {
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #333;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  .nav-links.open {
    display: flex;
  }
  .nav-links ul {
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 10px 20px;
  }
  .nav-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/navigation.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title>Tax Corrector</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="logo">Tax Corrector</div>
    <div class="nav-toggle"></div>
    <nav class="nav-links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome! Your `nav-toggle` has nothing in it. What were you expecting to happen? Is this missing the hamburger icon or something like a toggle?

Answer (score 0):

Your `.nav-toggle` toggle needs to have something in it, and it needs to be visible (not white on white).

But the main issue is that you're not calling your toggleMenu() function from anywhere. You need to call it when clicking on the toggle.

```js
function toggleMenu() {
  const navLinks = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
  navLinks.classList.toggle('open');
}
```

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.nav-links ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  /* display: inline; */
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.nav-links li {
  margin-right: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 1.2px;
}

.nav-links a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: black;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 200;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  color: black;
}

.nav-toggle {
  display: none;
  font-size: 42px;
  cursor: pointer;
/*  color: white; */
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav-links {
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #333;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    right: 0;
  }
  .nav-links.open {
    display: flex;
  }
  .nav-links ul {
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 10px 20px;
  }
  .nav-links a {
    color: white;
  }
  .nav-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
    <div class="logo">Tax Corrector</div>
    <div class="nav-toggle" onclick="toggleMenu()"></div>
    <nav class="nav-links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
```